# How to install Windows 7 on the same partition as Ubuntu 12.04 ie. dual boot?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have a Dell Vostro 3000 Series with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed.
I want to keep the Ubuntu and install Windows 7 Ultimate along with it.
The partition on which Ubuntu is installed is the only one with unused space and every time I try to Install Windows 7, it says "Windows cannot be installed on this Drive." and leaves me with the only option of deleting the partition, but I want to keep Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Do you know what you are asking about?

Comment: It is not called dual boot.

Comment: It is impossible to install windows which uses ntfs on partition of Ubuntu which uses ext or other linux file systems.

Answer (score 1):

You should shrink the partition from within Ubuntu (use GParted, or something similar). You then can use the unformatted space to create a NTFS partition using Windows.

Note that Windows annoyingly overwrites the boot-sector and insists on using the Windows bootloader, so you need to reinstall GRUB afterwards; see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

To install Window$ on drive with data you need:

For EFI boot:

- GPT partition table.
- EFI partition formatted as FAT16, preferably in the beginning of the drive.
- Empty space for window$ itself.

For non-EFI boot:

- MBR partition table
- Empty space for window$ bootloader in the beginning of the drive. - 150Mb suffice.
- Empty space for Window$ itself.

In both cases "empty space: means not the empty partition, and not the empty space of logical partition, but only a totally empty space.